# soundPool.load() inside (wait) Thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, soundpool

Hey I want to load sounds on a soundPool inside a Thread which contains a sleep command. The block I am talking about looks like that:

```
Thread wait = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       try {

          sleep(800);
          soundsMap.put(SOUND5, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.w5, 1));

       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // blub
       } finally {

       }
    }
 };
 wait.start();
```

Eclipse marks an error at `load` and writes:

> The method `load(Context, int, int)` in the type `SoundPool` is not applicable for the arguments `(new Thread(){}, int, int)`

Has anyone an idea how I can solve this? I don't really understand what the message wants to tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three-argument form of `SoundPool.load()` takes a `Context` reference as an argument.  `Activity` extends `Context`, so if you're writing code in an `Activity` sub-class you can just use `this`.

You're not doing that -- you're in a generic `Thread` instance -- and the compiler is letting you know.

To fix this you'll need to reference your `Activity` instance from your `Runnable` class, and pass that as the first argument to `load()`.